# PHP Include not working

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to use PHP's include function in conjunction with html but it is not working. I'm just messing around with the tag, it seems to be very simple but i cannot figure out why it is not working...

here is the template.php page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Template</title>
        <link href="css/layout.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="wrapper">

          <?php 
           include ("include/header.php");
           include ("include/leftcolumn.php"); 
           include ("include/rightcolumn.php"); 
           include ("include/footer.php"); 
           ?> 

     </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is the header.php page that I am trying to include:

```html
<header>
<p>Header.</p>
</header>
```

The only thing i could think of is the wrong directory, I have an include folder which is where the header.php is and referenced that in the include tag...unless I'm wrong, any tips? Thanks

[image: directory folder image]

Comment: How exactly does it not work? It displays an error message? The PHP tags are not parsed? The computer explodes?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
you dont need to use parenthesis try :

```
<?php 
           include "include/header.php";
           include "include/leftcolumn.php"; 
           include "include/rightcolumn.php"; 
           include "include/footer.php"; 
           ?>
```

and make sure the paths correct.

edit:

every exemple on the php manuel are dont have parenthesis.

And a question. where exectly you try to execute your php file. just in a browser or using any wamp server aplication to simulate server side action for your php ?

Comment: I was just about to answer the same thing +1

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I can't speak Turkish so I don't know if translators have made up something but the original English version only says: "parentheses are not needed" (not "parenthesis are forbidden").

Comment: I just want to know how he/she executes the php file. on browser? or using xampp like application?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested your code, but be sure of your path (is your template.php file to the root, before your include folder?) (it's crazy to say, but pathing are a frequent problem, and it can easily making you mad)

Or, try this syntax too :
include `'include/footer.php';`

Comment: So what's the problem in the original code? Also, you claim that removing the optional parenthesis of the `include` statement alters its behaviour—can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I have removed () and changed the syntax to 'include/footer.php'; i still am not having any luck..

Comment: Manual itself shows using parenthesis is not the best solution http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#function.include, I don't know exactly what's the problem in the original code, curious to know it !

Answer (score 0):

> Remove your Brackets ()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Template</title>
        <link href="css/layout.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="wrapper">

          <?php 
    // removing brackets... hopefully it will be working....
           include "include/header.php";
           include "include/leftcolumn.php"; 
           include "include/rightcolumn.php"; 
           include "include/footer.php"; 
           ?> 

     </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the issue and why does removing brackets fix it?

Comment: you had a syntactical problem. Please go through the PHP Manual Link mentioned beneath. Apparently your confusion will get turned into confident. :) Takecare. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php