# unable to use include() in my php file

Tags: php

i'm going to try to keep it as clear as i can, i've already made a fool of myself on the last question, but hey, i'm learning :)
so it goes like this: i have a db.php file in wich are my connection info, i'm trying to include this file from another server.php file. Now the code itself works, if i don't use include and i just put the code from db.php directly in the server.php it works fine. This is the db.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "severnam";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   
?>
```

and this is the server.php:

```
<?php
include(../php/db.php);
if (isset($_POST['count'])){
$sql = "SELECT content FROM flow";
$result = $conn->query($sql);   
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row["content"];
     }   
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}   
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

the files in cpanel are like this: [folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMWQX.png) i'm obvios doing something wrong... thanks!also while we're on the subject, can anyone point me in the right direction as to properly organising my files on the server, witch one should go where... thanks again.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP Include not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178745/php-include-not-working/42178786#42178786)

try to remove parenthesis from your include.

```
    <?php
// if file way is like that
    include "db/db.php";
    if (isset($_POST['count'])){
    $sql = "SELECT content FROM flow";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);   
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo $row["content"];
         }   
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }   
    $conn->close();
    }
    ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

and check for more information

edit:

just realized there is no php folder in your `puplic_html` check the location. if db folder contains the `db.php` than I correct the code.

Comment: for my experience paranthesis are problem. and in the manuel there is no usage of paranthesis.

Comment: for my experience it never create a problem (parenthesis)

Comment: to me it did... the path was right, the () were the problem.

Comment: @ValentinBaciu  that is first time i heard:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10918754/4248328 . I am agree that not needed, but creating problem, i am not agreed at all

Comment: like I sad. in my experiance. once my code not working because of parenthesis. but you know I just realized. I was using them like include("a.php"); instead of include ("a.php");. maybe the space is the key point :) if there is any space php trying to execute it like a function.

Comment: @Ahmet  exactly that is the problem

Comment: yep, both right, it was the space, it works with () but no space, thanks guys :)

Comment: @Ahmet was right both times, i'm not saying you were wrong :)